# How to modify a Java script file (*.js)? (It seems be codified)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to edit some parts of a .js file, but when I open it by notepad++ and change those parts, my site doesn't load at all. I see some unknown character in that file and think this problem refers to them. Somehow when I open the file and change it, that file doesn't match what it should be. (maybe the author places them in the file in order to protect his/her work or maybe I don't know the appropriate editor!!)

I'll send the link of that file and hope you can guide me to solve this problem:
http://students.sbu.ac.ir/r.bastani/wp-content/themes/ceevee/js/plugins.js

Comment: What unknown character are you referring to? This appears to just be a JS file containing a bunch of minified libraries.

Comment: @rahulmr I like VSCode, but your comment doesn't help OP in the slightest as Notepad++ is perfectly capable of modifying JavaScript files.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie You can see those characters by notepad++ on line 23 after " backgroundPosition:["X Y","0% 0%"] " and on line 43 after "c.paper=c.root"

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

As @AndroidNoobie metioned, this is a bunch of minified libraries, so be very carefully, when you edit this file.

To make editing with notepad++ a bit easier, you should install the extension JSTool. You can install extensions by clicking on Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> Show  Plugin Manager. Then search for JSTool.

When installed JSTool and opened that JS file, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. This will format the code, and it is much better readable.

Regarding to you question: When you execute this file with Google Chrome, open the DevTool (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and navigate to the Console tab. This will give you a better overview of what concrete characters are unknown.

The characters you mentioned in line 23 and 43 should not be unknown to JS (curly braces and commas). Maybe formatting the code helps you. If not, please provide more information about what is unknown.

**EDIT**

The files seems not to be loaded completely:
[image: image here]

There are also some other errors in the console:
[image: image here]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I installed that plugin and only use from "CTRL + ALT + M" to format codes and then upload that file to the server. You can see the results: http://students.sbu.ac.ir/r.bastani/fa

Comment: My problem is when I open this file (plugins.js) and any minor change occur the site can't load truly, this astonishes me.

Comment: Any minor changes in that file (include format codes with jstools) lead to a big problem in making some functions and this causes problem in loading my website

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Those parts which don't load completely are those I cited them as unknown characters. For example, your first picture is located on line 23 of the original file. The interesting matter is when I upload the original file, all of these errors disappear. The problem lies somewhere in the codes of this file (plugins.js) but I can't understand what it is.

Comment: what webserver are your using? nginx?

Comment: or if you use IIS, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510497/jquery-script-getting-cut-off-when-accessed-via-reverse-proxy

Comment: My web server is Apache 2.4.27.